# Azure - Custom Domain - Advanced Management

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 custom domains, which i bought via Microsoft Azure like 2 months ago.
I logged in today to check the portability on GoDaddy, and i did it by:

1. Log in in Azure
2. Click on one of my domain
3. Click on - Custom Domain
4. Advanced management

and after i click on Advanced management instead of taking me to godaddy, it redirects back to Azure Dashboard.

Is this a bug? Or i need to do more than this simple queries.

Thank you,

Comment: On my side. After clicked the Advanced Management link, our browser will open ext.azure.com as a temp site. After few senconds, it will redirect to godady management portal automatically. Which browser did you use ? I tested it by IE 11.  Or it maybe a temporary issue of Azure portal. Please try it later.